# Is there a 'min' function in firestore

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have documents stored in Firestore with a 'count' element that when is needed I want to get the one with the minimum 'count' value.

Do I must get all the documents and search the min value on the client side?
Or is there some other way?

I'm using firebase python client if relevant.

Comment: Firestore does not offer any aggregation queries (sum, min, max, avg, etc).  You will need to come up with another solution. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation

Comment: I think the OP didn't ask for  aggregate COUNT. He used a column named COUNT. If I am correct, @omer can check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data